# Flashing TWRP.img on Xiaomi Mi A3 to root the device does not work

Tags: twrp, xiaomi, sim-unlocking, mi

Working on Ubuntu 20.04. I want to root my device to uninstall some apps (.apk) and possibly also install Ubuntu Touch. I want to uninstall almost all Google apps because I don't have a Google account and I don't want to. Without a Google account, you cannot use most Google applications (Gmail, YouTube, Drive...).

A few months ago when I bought the device, I unlocked the bootloader, but I didn't have time to root it. Now I want to root it.

I followed these [TWRP for Xiaomi Mi A3](https://twrp.me/xiaomi/xiaomimia3.html) instructions and cannot flash or boot the TWRP.img.

1. I downloaded: [twrp-installer-3.4.0-0-laurel_sprout.zip](https://dl.twrp.me/laurel_sprout/twrp-installer-3.4.0-0-laurel_sprout.zip.html) and [twrp-3.4.0-0-laurel_sprout.img](https://dl.twrp.me/laurel_sprout/twrp-3.4.0-0-laurel_sprout.img.html) renamed it to **twrp.img** and **twrp-installer.zip**.
2. I copied the files to the device in **/sdcard**

---

```
adb devices
adb push ~/Downloads/twrp.img /sdcard
adb push ~/Downloads/twrp-installer.zip /sdcard
adb reboot-bootloader
```

---

```
fastboot devices
```

---

```
fastboot flashing unlock
...
FAILED (remote:         Device already : unlocked!)
finished. total time: 0.000s
```

---

```
fastboot flashing unlock_critical
...
OKAY [  0.026s]
finished. total time: 0.026s
```

---

```
fastboot flashing get_unlock_ability
...
(bootloader) get_unlock_ability: 1
OKAY [  0.000s]
finished. total time: 0.000s
```

---

```
fastboot boot twrp.img
downloading 'boot.img'...
OKAY [  1.174s]
booting...
FAILED (remote: unknown command)
finished. total time: 1.175s
```

---

```
fastboot flash recovery twrp.img
target reported max download size of 804261888 bytes
sending 'recovery' (39892 KB)...
OKAY [  1.172s]
writing 'recovery'...
FAILED (remote: (recovery_a) No such partition)
finished. total time: 1.174s
```

---

Did I do something wrong? How can I root the device?

To recover the device follow this instructions: https://c.mi.com/oc/miuidownload/detail?guide=2

--EDIT--

```
fastboot getvar current-slot
current-slot: a
finished. total time: 0.002s
```

---

```
fastboot --set-active=b
Setting current slot to 'b'...
OKAY [  0.039s]
finished. total time: 0.039s
```

---

```
fastboot flash boot twrp.img
target reported max download size of 804261888 bytes
sending 'boot_b' (39892 KB)...
OKAY [  1.181s]
writing 'boot_b'...
OKAY [  0.207s]
finished. total time: 1.388s
```

Press and hold **volume up button** on device and enter the command **fastboot reboot**
Back in Fastboot

[image: Android-Fastboot]

---

```
fastboot --set-active=a
Setting current slot to 'a'...
OKAY [  0.039s]
finished. total time: 0.039s
```

Press and hold **volume up button** on device and enter the command **fastboot reboot**

[image: Android-No-Command]

Do not press any key boots in Android-OS

Comment: Are you trying to root? If so you need Magisk, see [instructions](https://forum.xda-developers.com/mi-a3/how-to/guide-how-to-root-mi-a3-magisk-t3958509). Just by flashing TWRP, you are only changing recovery from stock to custom //XDA is the best place to read up on such things and you'd need to do that first

Comment: ** the same path where you have adb and fastboot** I do not understand that.
Does this mean that I should switch to the **/home/USER/Downloads/** folder?

Comment: I can't answer that. You'd better ask in XDA

Comment: I followed the guide and now my device only starts in Fasboot-mode. No longer boots normally in Android-OS. No problem I can fix it but it didn't work.

Comment: I am sorry but I can't help

Comment: **try TWRP 3.3.1-2...** same thing

Comment: @alecxs, I downloaded the MIUI10. On which partition should I flash it? To the **boot**, **recovery** or... ?

Comment: No images inside the .zip **care_map.txt, compatibility, compatibility.zip, META-INF  payload.bin, payload_properties.txt**

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112028/discussion-between-teso-and-alecxs).

Answer (score 0):

If your active slot is A, change it to active slot B. Then flash `twrp.img` and reboot the phone while pressing the volume key "+". Now you are in the recovery and you have to reinstall it in slot A. For doing this, change the active slot to A and press install, and select again `twrp.img`.